# Python3: string input in file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, path

I have a kind of weather station data files from several locations. I'd like to call them by simply writing the name, e.g:

```
import pandas as pd
location = 'sample'
file = '/home/saulo/experimental/inmet_auto/'location'_auto_201903.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=11, header=None)
```

But this way is not possible. How could I open the file properly?